# Perfect powers of numbers which can fit in 64 bit size integer (using priority queues)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, priority-queue

How can we print out all perfect powers that can be represented as 64-bit long integers: 4, 8, 9, 16, 25, 27, .... A perfect power is a number that can be written as ab for integers a and b ≥ 2. 
It's not a homework problem, I found it in job interview questions section of an algorithm design book. Hint, the chapter was based on priority queues.

Most of the ideas I have are quadratic in nature, that keep finding powers until they stop fitting 64 bit but that's not what an interviewer will look for. Also, I'm not able to understand how would PQ's help here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a small priority queue, with one entry per power, is a reasonable way to list the numbers.  See following python code.

```
import Queue             # in Python 3 say:  queue
pmax, vmax = 10, 150
Q=Queue.PriorityQueue(pmax)
p = 2
for e in range(2,pmax):
    p *= 2
    Q.put((p,2,e))

print 1,1,2
while not Q.empty():
    (v, b, e) = Q.get()
    if v < vmax:
        print v, b, e
        b += 1
        Q.put((b**e, b, e))
```

With pmax, vmax as in the code above, it produces the following output.  For the proposed problem, replace `pmax` and `vmax` with `64` and `2**64`.

```
1 1 2
4 2 2
8 2 3
9 3 2
16 2 4
16 4 2
25 5 2
27 3 3
32 2 5
36 6 2
49 7 2
64 2 6
64 4 3
64 8 2
81 3 4
81 9 2
100 10 2
121 11 2
125 5 3
128 2 7
144 12 2
```

The complexity of this method is O(vmax^0.5 * log(pmax)).  This is because the number of perfect squares is dominant over the number of perfect cubes, fourth powers, etc., and for each square we do O(log(pmax)) work for `get` and `put` queue operations.  For higher powers, we do O(log(pmax)) work when computing `b**e`.

When `vmax,pmax  =64, 2**64`, there will be about 2*(2^32 + 2^21 + 2^16 + 2^12 + ...) queue operations, ie about 2^33 queue ops.

*Added note:* This note addresses cf16's comment, “one remark only, I don't think "the number of perfect squares is dominant over the number of perfect cubes, fourth powers, etc." they all are infinite. but yes, if we consider finite set”.  It is true that in the overall mathematical scheme of things, the cardinalities are the same.  That is, if `P(j)` is the set of all `j`'th powers of integers, then the cardinality of `P(j) == P(k)` for all integers `j,k > 0`.  Elements of any two sets of powers can be put into 1-1 correspondence with each other.

Nevertheless, when computing perfect powers *in ascending order*, no matter how many are computed, finite or not, the work of delivering squares dominates that for any other power.  For any given *x*, the density of perfect *k*<sup>th</sup> powers in the region of *x* declines exponentially as *k* increases.  As *x* increases, the  density of perfect *k*<sup>th</sup> powers in the region of *x* is proportional to (*x*<sup>1/k</sup>)/*x*, hence third powers, fourth powers, etc become vanishingly rare compared to squares as *x* increases.

As a concrete example, among perfect powers between 1e8 and 1e9 the number of (2; 3; 4; 5; 6)th powers is about (21622; 535; 77; 24; 10).  There are more than 30 times as many squares between 1e8 and 1e9 than there are instances of any higher powers than squares.  Here are ratios of the number of perfect squares between two numbers, vs the number of  higher perfect powers: 10¹⁰–10¹⁵, r≈301; 10¹⁵–10²⁰, r≈2K; 10²⁰–10²⁵, r≈15K; 10²⁵–10³⁰, r≈100K.  In short, as *x* increases, squares dominate more and more when perfect powers are delivered in ascending order.

Comment: @Jirka, there are about 2^32 squares, 2^21 cubes, 2^16 fourth powers, etc., less than 2^64.  One could keep queue entries only for powers above 2, and keep squares in a separate local variable, so algorithm time would drop to O(vmax^0.5).  But with lg(pmax)=8, the log(pmax) factor is fairly small anyway.  Also, queue time could be cut in half if a Q.replace() op were available to replace the least entry and then re-heapify (assuming a heap data structure), vs pop the min, re-heapify, add new power, re-heapify as it's doing now.

Comment: @Jirka, the queue in my answer never has more than 62 entries in it, and takes at most a KB or two.  Each entry has three numbers in it: value, base, exponent.  The queue has one entry per possible exponent, 2, 3, 4, ... 63.

Comment: And again you are right.  Yes, you are incrementing the base not the exponent.  I only regret that I cannot upvote your answer again now.

Comment: @jwpat7, when we're inserting numbers in the priority queue initially then we should insert other numbers such as (49,7,2) or (36,6,2) etc.. They'd be legit perfect powers too..

Comment: @user1071840, no, those don't need to be in initial queue.  When (4,2,2) pops out, then (9,3,2) goes in; when (9,3,2) pops out, (16,4,2) goes in; similarly through (25,5,2), (36,6,2), (49,7,2), etc.  (Generally, when (b^e, b, e) pops out, ((b+1)^e, b+1, e) goes in, which is why there are no more queue entries, at any given time, than there are possible exponents.)

Comment: @jwpat7 one remark only, I don't think "the number of perfect squares is dominant over the number of perfect cubes, fourth powers, etc." they all are infinite. but yes, if we consider finite set

Comment: @cf16, I added a note about that

Comment: @jwpat7 what is "x" in your note?

Comment: @cf16, *x* stands for any positive number.  Or think of it as the argument to a function, like Density(2,x) and  Density(3,x) might stand for the marginal density of squares or cubes in the vicinity of x.

Answer (score 2):

A priority queue helps, for example, if you want to avoid duplicates in the output, or if you want to list the values particularly sorted.

Priority queues can often be replaced by sorting and vice versa.  You could therefore generate all combinations of a<sup>b</sup>, then sort the results and remove adjacent duplicates.  In this application, this approach appears to be slightly but perhaps not drammatically memory-inefficient as witnessed by [one of the sister answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12967979/1235565).

A priority queue can be superior to sorting, if you manage to remove duplicates as you go; or if you want to avoid storing and processing the whole result to be generated in memory.   The [other sister answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12968703/1235565) is an example of the latter but it could easily do both with a slight modification.

Here it makes the difference between an array taking up ~16 GB of RAM and a queue with less than 64 items taking up several kilobytes at worst.  Such a huge difference in memory consumption also translates to RAM access time versus cache access time difference, so the memory lean algorithm may end up much faster even if the underlying data structure incurs some overhead by maintaining itself and needs more instructions compared to the naive algorithm that uses sorting.

Because the size of the input is fixed, it is not technically possible that the methods you thought of have been quadratic in nature.  Having two nested loops does not make an algorithm quadratic, until you can say that the upper bound of each such loop is proportional to input size, and often not even then).  What really matters is how many times the innermost logic actually executes.

In this case the competition is between feasible constants and non-feasible constants.

Comment: Thank you. very nicely explained.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can see the priority queue making much sense is that you want to print numbers as they become available, in strictly increasing order, and of course without printing any number twice. So you start off with a prime generator (that uses the sieve of eratosthenes or some smarter technique to generate the sequence 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, ...). You start by putting a triple representing the fact that 2^2 = 4 onto the queue. Then you repeat a process of removing the smallest item (the triple with the smallest exponentiation result) from the queue, printing it, increasing the exponent by one, and putting it back onto the queue (with its priority determined by the result of the new exponentiation). You interleave this process with one that generates new primes as needed (sometime before p^2 is output).

Since the largest exponent base we can possibly have is 2^32 (2^32)^2 = 2^64, the number of elements on the queue shouldn't exceed the number of primes less than 2^32, which is [evidently 203,280,221](http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/98/pi_x), which I guess is a tractable number.

Comment: @rici oops, not primes then. I guess I screwed up. You actually want to allow any number as a base *unless* it's of the form a^b itself. And... there are probably way more of those than primes. The technique still works, but the memory usage gets stupid-er. I'll come back to it in the morning unless someone beats me to a better solution. :)

Comment: A better solution would probably capitalize on the fact that x^19 = x^16 * x^2 * x for any given x (and of course likewise for any given power), and so build higher powers off of lower ones in some better way than simply counting up by one.